# laravel 5.6 - get data of multiple layers of parent-child with belongs to many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Imagine I have a site with a lots of `catalogs` which have `sections` and with each `section`, i have `items`.

- `catalogs` is `belongstomany` with `sections`.
- `sections` is `belongstomany` with `items`.

What I want for final result is to have a nest data with:

```
{
  "catalog_id": 1,
  "catalog_name": "catalog 01",
  "sections": [
    {
      "section_id": 1,
      "name": "section 01",
      "items": [
        {
          "item_id": 1,
          "item_content": {
            "name": "some content1"
          }
        },
        {
          "item_id": 2,
          "item_content": {
            "name": "some content2"
          }
        },
        {
          "item_id": 3,
          "item_content": {
            "name": "some content3"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "section_id": 2,
      "name": "section 02",
      "items": [
        {
          "item_id": 2,
          "item_content": {
            "name": "some content2"
          }
        },
        {
          "item_id": 3,
          "item_content": {
            "name": "some content3"
          }
        },
        {
          "item_id": 4,
          "item_content": {
            "name": "some content4"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Technically I can use `each-loop` to get whatever I want, but I hope that is a better solution in `Eloquent`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Catalogs::with('sections.items')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add to @J.Doe answer that you can specify what you want to do. for example

```
Catalogs::with([
   'sections' => function($query){
       return $query->select('column')
              ->where('someCondition', 1)
              ->orderBy('id', 'asc');
   'items' => //some other stuff
];
```

you can also use method `with()` for your relation. lets say `sections` related to `someTable`. if you have relation method `someTable` in your `section` model, then:

```
Catalogs::with([
   'sections' => function($query){
       return $query->select('column')
              ->with('someTable') // here's your relation 
              ->where('someCondition', 1)
              ->orderBy('id', 'asc');
   'items' => //some other stuff
];
```